# Using cookies from homepage to access subpage on Axios (JS)

Tags: javascript, http, axios

I am trying to access a subpage of https://termmasterschedule.drexel.edu/, an example would be https://termmasterschedule.drexel.edu/webtms_du/courseList/ANIM. I need to get the cookies from the homepage, including the session ID, and use them to access the subpage.

I have no clue where to start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi! A good place to start would be reading [how cookies work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) (hint: the server sends it in an HTTP response header called Cookie) and [Axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) to understand how to extract the cookie from the server's response (hint: the response you get via Axios has a "headers" attribute, you could print it out to see what's inside it).